# PinTool catches instrumented application exceptions

Tags: pintool

How can I catch the exceptions generated by an instrumented application in Intel PIN?

I know about `PIN_AddInternalExceptionHandler`. This is not what I mean, this catches exceptions generated by the PinTool itself (if I understood correctly)

I found this [resource](http://scrammed.blogspot.de/2013/03/binary-instrumentation-for-exploit_10.html). Although it is a clever solution (check EIP against `KiUserExceptionDispatcher`) I can not instrument every instruction in my case.

Is there a simple way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use PIN_AddContextChangeFunction, and from callback (CONTEXT_CHANGE_CALLBACK) you may see exception